# x symbol in the first position of imported data in R

Tags: r, csv, import

I an just a novice to R.
Trying to import a .csv file, I get the below result

```
     X.Bin1.Bin2.Bin3
1      Scan1;10;20;30
2      Scan2;60;50;40
3      Scan3;70;80;90
```

Can not find any explanation what does X. symbol mean and how it is treated by R.
BR Vladimir

Comment: It looks like you don't really have a CSV file because CSV files are by definition separated by commas and your data seems to have semicolons between values. Use `sep=";"` with `read.table()` to properly import your data. But it's likely that i'll still have an x for the first column for the reason described in the question link above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use `colnames()` or `rownames`. **X.** is the default name of column names usually ,used by R, when a dataframe is generated.

You can also use `row.names = FALSE` or `col.names` or col.names = FALSE when you import the data. 
It isn't clear if rows or columns are the ones with the X.